# How to run cypress run and cypress open at a time with this user can see the cases are performed on web the same report are generated

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner, mochawesome

How to run cypress run and cypress open at a time with this user can see the cases are performed on web the same report are generated

I want to run npx cypress open and npx cypress run at a time so that is performed, and user view and same report generate. It will run cypress instance at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to see the execution for a `cypress run` and wanting to get the report, you should use `--headed` [option](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run). This will show the browser during execution.

```
npx cypress run --headed
```